# tomcat deny access to specific files

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a webapp in Tomcat with a main JSP file that includes another JSP file in the center of the page. I want to deny access to that file directly, and only allow direct access to the main index page.

Also, I don't want users to be able to get images from my webapp directly.

How can I deny those requests with Tomcat? I want all of the requests to forward to my main page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to implement a [`Filter`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

For example:

```
package package;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class FilterImplementation implements Filter
{
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {...}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // if you detect an illegal request, throw an exception or return without calling chain.doFilter.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);     
    }

    public void destroy() {...}
}
```

add the following to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>package.FilterImplementation</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**EDIT**

Everything you need to know about which page is being requested is in the `request` parameter. The parameter type is [`ServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) however it will almost always be an [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) so you can do the following:

```
if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
{
    HttpServletRequest hrequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String uri = hrequest.getRequestURI(); // you should be able to just use this
    String uri = hrequest.getRequestURL(); // otherwise there are more in-depth fields
}
```

Comment: how can i get the requested page ?

Answer (score 9):

From the page [Prevent access to include files](http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Prevent+access+to+include+files) .

Add in web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Include files</web-resource-name>
        <description>No direct access to include files.</description>
        <url-pattern>/inc/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>No direct browser access to include files.</description>
        <role-name>NobodyHasThisRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Regarding the included JSP files, you should place them under `WEB-INF` folder. This way, they are not accessible directly from the browser, yet it allows your main JSP file to include them.
2. The same thing with images, but images are a little bit tricky, yet doable. Place them under `WEB-INF` folder, and because of that, you can't access the images statically from the `<img>` tag. What you will need to do is to create a servlet that serves as a proxy to get the image and stream it out... so, your `<img>` looks something like this:-

==========

```
<img src="/webapp/imageServlet?img=world.jpg">
```

==========

Your `ImageServlet` will then read `world.jpg` file from `WEB-INF` folder and stream the image out.