# How do I restrict .well-known/openid-configuration url

Tags: openam, forgerock

I have done the setup Access Management(OPENAM) version 6.5.0.1.
I can directly access .well-known/openid-configuration via below url without login

```
http://XXXXXXXX:8080/openam/oauth2/realms/root/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Is there any way to restrict this url or only admin user can access this url.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @jonasheinisch: We don't want to show all the endpoint points details. Issue raised by security team

Comment: Maybe it's an option to block the request to this path by tomcat? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333266/tomcat-deny-access-to-specific-files However, in general, it's just security by obscurity. This will not increase the security of the page massively...

Comment: Well this is OpenID Connect Discovery, you need it in order to allows clients to retrieve OpenID Provider configuration